# Specifying and interpreting multilevel nested model for meta-analysis of GM crops

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, meta-analysis

I'm looking at a metadataset of studies of the yields of genetically modified crops.  For each study, I have one or more reported findings (increases in yield due to genetic modification), and some study-level metadata:  crop species (one of maize, cotton, or soybeans), country type (developed or developing), GM event type (either insect-resistant or herbicide-resistant), whether the study used regression, study type (either experimental field trial or farmer survey), whether the study was sponsored by industry, and whether the study was published in a peer-reviewed journal.

For each of those study-level variables, I'd like to get an estimate of its effect on the findings, taking into account the fact that findings are nested into studies to control for study bias.  This means I want a 3-level model, with findings on the bottom, study in between, and the variables of interest on the top.

Reading around about the syntax `lme4::lmer` uses for nesting, it seems like the following formula will do what I want:

```
endpoint ~ 0 + (1|crop/study) + (1|event/study) + 
                (1|regression/study) + (1|country/study) + 
                (1|study_type/study) + (1|industry/study) +
                (1|journal/study)
```

Specifically, I can hand this formula to either `lme4::lmer` or `rstanarm::stan_lmer` (the latter has a more convenient tidier in `broom`).  The fitted model gives estimates for interaction terms between the variables of interest and the individual studies — which I believe I don't care about — and the following — which I believe that I do care about:

```
         level      group        term    estimate std.error
1       cotton       crop (Intercept)  0.63136245  2.484556
2        maize       crop (Intercept) -0.01947010  2.284912
3      soybean       crop (Intercept) -0.07913682  2.425395
4        FALSE    journal (Intercept) -2.77214601  7.643130
5         TRUE    journal (Intercept)  9.37080482  8.372829
6        FALSE   industry (Intercept)  0.86931739  4.280512
7         TRUE   industry (Intercept)  0.23544865  4.232657
8       survey study_type (Intercept)  2.22262385  4.495824
9  field_trial study_type (Intercept) -0.32424589  4.108007
10   developed    country (Intercept) -2.31048095  7.121554
11  developing    country (Intercept)  7.69356622  8.594535
12       FALSE regression (Intercept) -0.35844890  3.650564
13        TRUE regression (Intercept)  2.03837270  4.111827
14          HT      event (Intercept) -0.04189164  3.508054
15          IR      event (Intercept)  1.17481409  3.732732
```

I want to interpret these rows as estimates and standard errors of the effect/group value for each level of my covariates.  For instance, cotton is associated with a finding (yield increase due to genetic modification) of about 0.6 units (percentage points), with a standard error of about 2.5 units (percentage points).

I've pieced together several different tutorials to get to this point, so I don't have very high confidence that I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: Your model specification does not make any sense. Do I understand correctly that each `study` contributes only 1 data point to your model? I.e. each study is characterized by 1 value each of `crop`, `journal`, etc., and there is 1 outcome `endpoint` per study?

Comment: No; there are approximately 130 studies and 400 data points; I believe the median study has 5 data points.  For a given study, the values of `crop`, `journal`, and so on are the same.  For example, study `001` might have 3 data points, all concerning cotton in developing countries, and study `005` might have 7 data points, all concerning soybeans in developed countries.

Comment: Then it should probably be `endpoint ~ crop + event + regression + country + study_type + industry + journal + (1|study)`, i.e. all your factors are fixed effects, there is one random intercept for `study`, and no nesting.

Comment: I've considered something like that.  But that model treats the study effects as independent of the various covariates.  Given the data structure, I'd like to model the study effects as dependent on the covariates.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what this would mean for your dataset. I don't think you have much choice here. As I said, the model you wrote does not make sense. When you include e.g. `(1|journal/study)` term it means `(1|journal)+(1|journal:study)`. The first term does not make sense because `journal` has only two levels and is clearly not random, so it should be fixed not random. And the second term does not make sense because there is no journal/study interaction in your data: each study has only 1 value of journal. Hence this should be replaced by fixed `journal` effect, as I suggested.

Comment: Have you considered the same approach but using a random effects model in `metafor`? (An alternative is `metaSEM`). You would need a vector of effects (e.g., standardized mean difference, correlation, etc.) and a vector of the variance for each effect to start. You could include potential study-level moderators in your model as well, which seems of interest. You can explore more of the package's functionality [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php).

Comment: Following up on @Amoeba, who correctly points out that you can't estimate a study:journal interaction, you *could* estimate a random effect for study and another random effect for journal.  In the most transparent possible syntax, that would be (1|journal) + (1|study).  This is identifiable iff some journals contain more than one study.  If you really think that a single study should have different random effects for each of its multiple crops, countries, etc, you might consider estimating a random effect of observation (i.e. each data point gets its own independent random offset).

Comment: @user43849 "random effect of observation" is estimated in any case - it's residual variation.

Comment: @Amoeba  Agreed, but only if the model uses an error structure that is normal on the link scale.  I don't think there's enough info in the question to determine whether this is the case. Edit: never mind, I see the poster is using lmer (and not glmer) so you're right--sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user43849 Yes, but I agree that it's sometimes a useful trick with glmer, e.g. to model overdispersion in logistic regression with family=binomial.